# bootstrap make 3 textboxes inline

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve this:
[image: Inline image]

But I tried many things still can't. My result is this:
[image]

Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group-sm  col-sm-4">
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="PD Number"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group-sm  col-sm-4">                                                            
                <div class="form-control-inline"><asp:TextBox ID="txtPDNumber1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control  input-sm"></asp:TextBox></div>
                <div class="form-control-inline"> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPDNumber2" CssClass="form-control input-xs" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>                        
                <div class="form-control-inline"> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPDNumber3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm"></asp:TextBox></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On top of the page I have:

```
<style>
    .form-control-inline {
        position: relative !important;
        display: inline !important;
        width: 30% !important;
    }
</style>
```

Here is rendered html:

```
                    <span>PD Number</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group-sm  col-sm-4">                                                            
                <div class="form-control-inline"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtADNumber1" type="text" value="34" id="MainContent_txtAPDNumber1" class="form-control  input-sm" /></div>
                <div class="form-control-inline"> <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtAPDNumber2" type="text" id="MainContent_txtPDNumber2" class="form-control input-xs" /></div>                        
                <div class="form-control-inline"> <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtAPDNumber3" type="text" id="MainContent_txtPDNumber3" class="form-control input-sm" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How do I adjust to make them inline. Also adjust the width of the textbox.

Comment: Try remove css class from asp:TextBox. Also, please paste your rendered html here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using bootstrap grids. Something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPDNumber1"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPDNumber2"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPDNumber3"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms) and [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms), there is a class you can add to a `form` element called `form-inline`, which will place your `input` elements on the same row. It's tough to determine from the provided code, but wrapping your input elements with a `form` tag and adding the `form-inline` class you might get your desired output.

Note: When a responsive breakpoint is reached, these elements will go be displayed on their own rows.

https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/QMZQjv... This will show you the code inaction.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput1" placeholder="">
      <span>-</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput2" placeholder="">
      <span>-</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput3" placeholder="">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```